# What is the calabash step for communicating to mobile time settings

Tags: iphone, calabash

I am new to calabash and kind of stuck in this:

I am writting a feature file for mobile app (testing in iphone). According to the user story, I need to change my mobile's time from am to pm and vice-versa from the Settings>General>Time and see the affect on the app.

I almost searched everywhere if there is any step like -

Then I set the time......from settings
or
Then I change device time from settings
or
Then I change am to pm .....

Please help me to get a solution or a better search for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not able to find any way of doing this either. As you probably know you can change language with "calabash-ios sim ". So I had expected to find some similar command, but I have not been able to either.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible it interact with the Settings.app on iOS devices.

I don't think it is possible on the simulator either because the simulator time uses the host machine's clock.